# creating dummy variables using dummyVars()and ifelse(), are there difference?

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I am writing to ask the usual way of creating or binarization dummy variables.

I have been referencing to many different books and there are two ways:

using `dummyVars` under the package `caret` or using `ifelse`

Can anyone tell the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ifelse`, there is no direct/intuitive way to create dummy variables for variables more than two factors. In this case, `ifelse` is most useful for simple binary variables -- either yes or no, someone smokes or not.

Functions like `dummyVars` or `dummy_cols` on the other hand, give you the ability to create dummies for variables with multiple factors with ease. These functions are more approachable when you're dealing with non-binary categorical variables, which can also be handy when you want interactions in between.